# Android Emulator Snapshot file location

Tags: android, adb, snapshot

I'd like to know where Android Emulator Snapshots are stored on disc.
I know how to take them via Extended Control but I can't find them on disc. I did a filesystem search but no hits. The idea is to share them with my team.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To retrieve the saved snapshot on disc, you have to go to the AVD location.
In Android Virtual Device Manager, right click on your AVD, then **show on disc**. You will find a directory call **snapshots**

Comment: Really ? On my side, when I click on the camera button, a screenshot is stored at the specified location. How do you take screenshot ?

Comment: I m talking about snapshot not screenshot

Comment: @Mr.Stef, my bad to have mix snapshot and screenshot ^^. I've edited my answer

Answer (score 86):

[image: Press for 3 dots]

[image: Then Press the Settings and in top right corner you will see the screenshot folder location]

Press for 3 dots. Then Press the Settings and in top right corner you will see the screenshot folder location.

Comment: Snapshots not screenshots. :-)

Comment: There are no "screenshot location" folder anymore.

Answer (score 23):

There's now a setting for this in the Emulator itself. In the options menu, tap on the Three Dots button to open Extended Controls. Tap the 'Settings' item in the left-hand list and you'll see 'Screenshot save location', which is an editable field.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the location of emulator-made snapshots.

**Windows user:**

```js
%USERPROFILE%\.android\avd\<AVD_NAME>\snapshots\
```

`%USERPROFILE%` is your current active user

Replace `<AVD_NAME>` with the name of your Android Virtual Device (AVD).

**Linux/macOS user:**

```bash
~/.android/avd/<AVD_NAME>/snapshots/
```

Replace `<AVD_NAME>` with the name of your Android Virtual Device (AVD).